# How to access variables of 1 function in another function defined within the same function in javascript

Tags: ajax

This is my JavaScript code.

```
function postFile(){
    var obj=new Object();
    obj.category=document.getElementsByName("gtitle")[0].value;
    obj=obj.stringify(obj);
    sendDetails("http://localhost:8080/Megabizz/webapi/gallery", obj);

    var r;

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            r=new Object(JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText));
            console.log(r.status);
        }
    };
//r not accessible here
}
```

In the function `postFile()`, I have a declared a variable `r` now I am manipulating this `r` using `ajaxRequest` object.
Now when I am trying to access this `r` outside the function `onreadystatechange()`,
I am getting an error that "r is undefined".

I think that the function `onreadystatechange()` is declaring a new variable `r` instead of manipulating `r` declared above the `onreadystatechange()` function.

Tell me the way to overcome this problem.

```
    //Another problem

var x;
function x(){
x=document.getElementByID("upload-buton");
}
function y(){
    x.value='some text';
}
```

In this case, the value of x which I am setting in function y() does not remain same for the function x().
I am getting an error "cannot set property value for undefined".

Please figure out the cause behind this error.

Comment: `r` is perfectly available there; it's just not available **yet**. Why would it be? The ajax call hasn't finished yet. If you want to do something with `r`, do it inside the ajax callback. PS: you might want to change the title of your question to something like "How to access variable coming back from ajax before the ajax call is finished".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: What you are doing here is the equivalent of ordering a pizza and then trying to eat it the moment you hang up the phone. It's not there yet.

Comment: hey, I edited the question check the part which is commented as "//another problem" in the last.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal If you have another question, please ask another question. Don't tack on a new one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) makes your code Asynchronous. That means that not everything in your code happens in a straightforward manner (the code might not be executed in the order it is written).

For basic understanding async code see a tutorial [Event-Based Programming: What Async Has Over Sync](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027).

`ajaxRequest.onreadystatechanges` fires on state change event. After that, you are comparing `ajaxRequest.readyState`, which means that however `r` variable is always accessible, it will be changed only on `4: request finished and response is ready` and will only be available after the completion of the Ajax request. Javascript will not wait for the Ajax request to finish.

A solution strongly depends on further actions you wish to do with `r` variable.